# Multisampling on iPad

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios4, multisampling

Is it possible to use multisampling on iPad ?

Apple's documentation say: "iOS4.0 and later devices", but all tutorials in inet says: "iPhone XX, IPAD"

I can't run my app under 3.2 sdk with multisampling (base sdk 4.1, deployment 3.2)

Is it possible ?
 Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible on iPad at the moment because the iPad runtime is 3.2 only.  The multisampling extension was introduced as of 4.0.

When the iPad OS version gets upgraded to 4.0 it will most likely support multisampling because the hardware is indeed capable of supporting multisampling.